# SharePoint 2016 - 401 Unauthorized on REST requests

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem

I feel like I am spinning in circles and can't figure out what I am missing. I have a SharePoint 2016 web application I am attempting to test the REST APIs through Postman with. I follow the guide I found at the following [site](http://www.whypad.com/posts/authenticate-sharepoint-rest-call-in-a-rest-client/1169/) to authenticate my requests. I get the FormDigestValue, add it to the X-RequestDigest header and make a subsequent request to get the lists on the site. Unfortunately, no matter what requests I make, I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
        }
    }
}
```

I have gone to the site collection, checked the users permission and the user has Full control permissions. The application is Claims based authentication. Is there anything else that I may be missing to check to get this to work as it does in the guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is about authentication.

You can enable Basic Authentification in IIS Settings, then in postman, select Basic Auth type and set your account name and password.
[image]

[Solution for 401 Unauthorized Error while Using configuring Postman to send REST request to SharePoint Server](http://ibtissamchabiba.blogspot.com/2017/03/solution-for-401-unauthorized-error.html)

Comment: Thanks, saved me a bunch of headaches. Simple change to make and as soon as I enabled basic authentication and went into postman and attempted a request, worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that will not work until you are passing credentials or the authentication token in the request. Request digest value is used only to prevent the cross-site scripting and not to authenticate the user.

To authenticate the current logged-in user you have to send one more header to the request to pass the credentials as:

```
 xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
```

And also you have to enable the **URL Rewrite** option in the IIS to prevent the preflight option from getting dropped. Please refer this [LINK](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242272/how-to-perform-post-operations-in-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-from-external-a/) to get it done.

Hope that helps.

Comment: While I appreciate this advice, the answer provided is for requests from ajax and does not apply to Postman. I have not attempted calls from Ajax but will keep note of this if I do attempt to.